# Show posts only on the future or today's date and hide those that are in the past (Worpdress) (ACF)

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type

Here is my code:

```php
      <?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'evenement', 'posts_per_page' => 10 ) ); ?>
      <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
  
          <a href="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>">
            <div class="image">
              <?php echo the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="description">
              <div class="dates">
                  <?php echo get_field('start_event') ?> à <?php echo get_field('hour_start_event') ?>
              </div>
              <div class="nom">
                <?php echo the_title(); ?>
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
  
      <?php endwhile; ?>
```

`get_field('start_event')` returns my custom field in this format and in french: *17 Novembre 2023*.

I would like to display only posts that are equal to or greater than today's date.

I've tried lots of things but I don't think I can do it. Thank you for your help!

I tried this below but it seems it only compares the day and not the rest of the date. If the day is a smaller number than today's day, it does not display it..

```php
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'evenement', 'posts_per_page' => 10 ) ); ?>
      <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

            <?php 
                $today = date("d/m/y");
                $date_event = date(get_field('start_event'));
            ?>

                        
  
                    <?php if (get_field('start_event') >= $today) { ?>
          <a href="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>">
            <div class="image">
              <?php echo the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="description">
              <div class="dates">
                  <?php echo get_field('start_event') ?> à <?php echo get_field('hour_start_event') ?>
              </div>
              <div class="nom">
                <?php echo the_title(); ?>
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
                    <?php }; ?>
  
      <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to ACF documentation, they can provide a thorough example, but you want to pass the metakey for your event date into the query args:

```
'meta_query' => array(
         array(
            'key'       => 'event_date',
            'compare'   => '>=',
            'value'     => $today,
        )
 ),
```

As an example against your code:

```
// Find today’s date in Ymd format.
    $today = date( 'Ymd' );

    // Query posts using a meta_query to compare two custom fields: start_date and end_date.
    $posts = get_posts( array(
        'post_type'  => 'evenement',
        'posts_per_page' => '10',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'start_event',
                'compare' => '>=',
                'value'   => $today,
            ),
        ),
    ) );
```

Your issue could be that you are using a different schema for today's date. Have you tried using Ymd format?